# I've been hacked what do I do?

Tags: attacks

I believe I may have been hacked, However I am not certain of this. I fear they are able to access my computer remotely. I have done several checks with advice from people online and it to some extent supports it. My question is now what do I do, I'd rather be safe than sorry  and want to take all precautions needed ( so in your answers please assume this is the case) I am not a computer genius and have no idea how I can fix it. So I have a few questions and I would really appreciate any help, thanks in advance:

- Since my computer has been hacked, can other devices using my wifi be hacked too or is it just an isolated incident.
- Should I reset my router to factory setting and contact my internet provider?
- Will destroying my laptop/resetting prevent any info being taken? Or should I wipe the hard drive? It's an old laptop, so if throwing it away is the only option I don't mind. This is probably my most important question as It would be the easiest.
- Once I have gotten rid of it what can I do to prevent being hacked in the future ?

I have changed all my passwords and stuff already, but I'm clueless right now so any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us how you know you've been hacked and how you know the attacker can control your computer and webcam remotely.

Comment: This is far too broad for us to answer, and we can only guess at what the hack did. As for how to fix it, we are not tech support or a virus removal forum. This is something that you need to talk to a tech about. The best advice we can give is to reformat the drives and to reinstall everything from backups.

Answer (score 4):

- I would wipe the hard drive but a second best thing is using virus/spyware scanners like [Avast](https://www.avast.com/), [Adaware](http://www.lavasoft.com/), [Spywaredoctor](http://download.cnet.com/s/spyware-doctor/). If the attacker is sophisticated this won't suffice.
- Modify all your passwords.
- If you use the same password to gain admin access to other devices on the network you can assume that they are compromised as well. So they should be wiped or cleaned. Passwords used on those devices should be reset.
  (by wipe, I mean reinstall, don't throw away)
- You probably configured your router so you might have given away that password. Do a factory reset on your router.
- Enable two factor authentication on all accounts like google (if they support it). Modifying passwords should only be done after the devices are clean, else the new password is compromised as well. Several sites like google allow you to check your login history. You can see if someone on the other side of the world logged in to your account. After you have enabled two factor authentication you should periodically check these same logging facilities to check if your account is still being used by someone else.

Logging facilities can tell you a lot about the attacker and allow you to verify if you are still a victim. Do you have any idea how they got into your system?

Don't forget to scan/wipe all USB/hard drives that you've connected to the infected computer lately.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful guys, I'll post a more detailed description soon